# Suggest a way to get specific email objects based on specific events

Tags: oop, design-patterns, factory

I have a Event hierarchy with some types of it namely WelcomeEvent, LogOffEvent, BilledEvent etc. I want to generate different kind of emails for these events. What I do is have a abstract Email class with types WelcomeEmail, LogoffEmail, BilledEmail.
I have a EmailFactory inside which I have following method:

```
Email getEmail(Event event) {
    if(event.instanceOf(WelcomeEvent))
        return new WelcomeEmail(event);
    if(event.instanceOf(LogOffEvent))
        return new LogoffEmail(event);
    if(event.instanceOf(LogOffEvent))
        return new BilledEmail(event);

}
```

My reviewer says that instanceOf should be avoided as much as possible.

> Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: why do you have different email classes in the first place?

Comment: WelcomeEmail picks up attributes of WelcomeEvent to create a appropriate email subject and body. Similarly for other specific emails.

Comment: Personally I don't see anything particularily wrong with your use case. It's a simple, maintable, factory.

Answer (score 0):

Make `getEmail` an instance method of your `Event` subclasses, that is abstract in the parent class `Event`. Pseudocode:

```
abstract class Event {
    abstract Email getEmail();
}

class WelcomeEvent < Event {
    Email getEmail() {
        return new WelcomeEmail();
    }
}

class LogOffEvent < Event {
    Email getEmail() {
        return new LogOffEmail();
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call `event.getEmail()` on any event to get a new `Email` that corresponds to its subclass.

Comment: so, the code would be `class WelcomeEvent{ Email getEmail() { return new WelcomeEmail(this);} }` ?